# Google Play Game Services iOS: [UITableViewWrapperView style]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-play, ios7, google-play-games

I have an application that uses Google Game Play services for iOS (v.1.1). I have a button that shows Achievements. It was working fine in iOS 6, but on iOS 7 I have this crash:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewWrapperView style]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b975750'
```

Here is my code:

```
BOOL signedIn = [[GPGManager sharedInstance] hasAuthorizer];

if (signedIn) {
    GPGAchievementController *achController = [[GPGAchievementController alloc] init];
    achController.achievementDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:achController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Anyone is experimenting this issue? Any possible workaround? I don't see any info in official Google Game Play Services doc.

Comment: You can probably set a breakpoint on "`[UITableViewWrapperView style]`" and catch the crash as it happens.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann unfortunately it crashes inside Google Play Game Services SDK. I can only see the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the crash happens at the "`presentViewController`" line and the crash is deep in the bowels of the Google Play Game Services SDK (which you and I don't have source code access to), you probably need to file a bug with them via the ["Bug Tracker" link on this page](http://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/).

And it looks like you (or somebody doing the exact same thing as you) [just reported it](https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=36&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Platform%20Summary%20Stars).  :-)

Comment: Yes Michael, I did it. I just want to find if I'm the only developer experimenting this, it's strange no one found this before. Or maybe no one is using Google Achievements on iOS yet :)

Comment: I'll wait until the Google Game Play Services team responses my bug report and I'll mark your answer as valid if it happens. Thank you!

Comment: A member of Google Team accepted this issue and it will be fixed in next release. TY!

Comment: Did you received any response yet from the Google team? Is there a link you can provide to the report you submitted? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: Update: this problem was fixed a week ago and it's already in the lastest download. source: https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=36